# how to show magnific-popup when youtube video finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, magnific-popup

i need to show a popup   when youtube video finish it works fine for the alert() but when i tried to make magnific popup instead if the alert it dosen't work here is my code

```
<script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '600',
        width: '600',
        videoId: 'id',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay':"0", 'controls':"1" },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
        });
    }

    var playerReady = false;
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        playerReady = true;
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED ) {            

  $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: 'mylink to the pic'
        },
        type: 'image'

      // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
      // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
    }, 0);  }
    }
</script>
```